# pack has bad object at offset 152904485

Tags: windows, git, gitlab

I'm trying to clone a repository on Gitlab with the command:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:company/folder/project.git
```

And every time I get this output:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 3860, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (482/482), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (360/360), done.
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 152904485: inflate returned 1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

The thing is, it happens only on my machine, I tested the exact same command accessing a linux machine remotely through `ssh` and it works just fine. Also, it's relevant to mention that I'm using `git` on Windows 11. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hm, you're cloning via ssh (`git@...:`) so it's not a badly behaved middleware box corrupting an https stream. How big is the repository? Is there a packfile that exceeds 2 GB?

Comment: Are you using a firewall or antivirus other than the default?  Are you using a proxy or TLS middlebox?

Comment: @torek The repository is close  to 250MB and as far as I know there are no files larger than 1GB

Comment: OK - that shouldn't exceed any limits that I know of...

Comment: @bk2204 No to both of your questions, and also I cloned another repository from my company, and it worked fine

Comment: What version of Git for windows are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAMe9rOrononRUYK0HmW_tknApUV+ZJeDBwOYMa1Ax-VHXZmoJQ@mail.gmail.com/T/#u), start checking the protocol used:

```
git -c protocol.version=1 clone git@gitlab.com:company/folder/project.git
```

As bit as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/HackingGate/bd5335b1f47e71b71f0134ae2fa7e7f2), you could try an incremental clone, using a shallow clone (`--depth`)

```bash
REPO=$1
DIR=$2
git clone --recurse-submodules $REPO $DIR --depth=1
cd $DIR
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch --depth=10
git fetch --depth=100
...
```

Another approach, clone up to the problematic commit: ([`--shallow-exclude=<revision>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---shallow-excludeltrevisiongt))

```bash
git clone --shallow-exclude=anOlCommit
```

There is a [patch in progress around index-pack](https://lore.kernel.org/git/YVaw6agcPNclhws8@coredump.intra.peff.net/) (June 2022), about [unpacking large object in a stream](https://public-inbox.org/git/5a4782d746a496e8edd1654296bac390d8e1c9d3.1654914555.git.chiyutianyi@gmail.com/T/#m69ad681a9b15db9699bf0354dcf5915bbbc08564).

---

The [OP Otávio Augusto Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12228795/ot%C3%A1vio-augusto-silva) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831506/pack-has-bad-object-at-offset-152904485/72836780?noredirect=1#comment128657673_72836780):

> It didn't worked on Windows 11 cmd but it worked on WSL2 (Ubuntu)

And since [Git can be installed on Windows *AND* on WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git), that could be a valid workaround.

Comment: It didn't worked on Windows 11 `cmd` but it worked on WSL2 (Ubuntu)

Comment: The command checking the protocol doesn't work for me. And in the thread you mentioned they use it this way: `git -c protocol.version=1 clone git@gitlab.com:company/folder/project.git`

Comment: @bdrnglm Thank you for the feedback, I forgot the clone there. I have edited the answer accordingly. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: The last one coming with Git for Windows (https://gitforwindows.org). Currently it is the `2.42`

Comment: @bdrnglm True. I am in the process of documenting [what is coming for 2.43](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a6309%202.43&searchOn=3). Nothing yet on protocol though.